# no such table SQLite error could not compile

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have three classes where the flow is..

1. entering the entry to be searched: (from MainActivity)

   ```
          try {
               String input = etSearch.getText().toString();
               Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchViewList.class);
               i.putExtra("input", input);
               Log.i("input", input + "");
               startActivity(i);  

           } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO: handle exception
               String error = e.toString();
               Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
               d.setTitle("Row Empty or ID not found!");
               TextView tv = new TextView(this);
               tv.setText(error);
               d.setContentView(tv);
               d.show();
               break;

           }
   ```
2. then the class SearchViewList would display the list by the searched value from the intent

   ```
           Intent i = getIntent();

   input = i.getStringExtra("input");

   String l = input;

   datasource = new DatabaseHelper(this);
   datasource.openDataBase();

   List<Definition> values = datasource.getSearchedDefinition(l);
   // use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
   // elements in a ListView
   ArrayAdapter<Definition> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Definition>(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
   setListAdapter(adapter);

   ListView listView = getListView();
   listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {
           // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           String str = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
           Log.i(str, str + "");

           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                   SearchedView.class);
           i.putExtra("value", str);
           startActivity(i);

       }
   });
   ```
3. then after clicking the searched entry from the list then the error commence

   ```
   Intent i = getIntent();

   l = i.getStringExtra("value");

   TextView entry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEntry);
   datasource = new DatabaseHelper(this);
   datasource.openDataBase();

   String dataEntry = datasource.getEntry(l);
   datasource.close();

   entry.setText(dataEntry);
   ```

   }

here is my getEntry() method from the DatabaseHelper class

```
public String getEntry(String l) throws SQLException {
        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT entry FROM defintionstbl where entry = '"
                        + l + "'", null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            if (c.getCount() <= 0) {
                return null;
            }
            String entry = c.getString(0);
            return entry;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

this next method is also from the DatabaseHelper class

```
public List<Definition> getSearchedDefinition(String l) throws SQLException {
        List<Definition> entries = new ArrayList<Definition>();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT entry FROM definitionstbl where entry like '" + l + "%'", null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Definition entry = cursorToDefinition(cursor);
            entries.add(entry);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();

        return entries;
    }

    private Definition cursorToDefinition(Cursor cursor) {
        Definition entry = new Definition();
        entry.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        entry.setEntry(cursor.getString(0));
        return entry;
    }
```

this method compile just fine but the i am getting a "no such table definitionstbl" error from the method getEntry().

```
additional note:
database = dictionary.sqlite
table = definitionstbl
column1 = _id
column2 = entry
column3 = definitions
```

here is the code for the copying of the database from an external source:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.gtxradeon.newversioncomputerdictionary/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "dictionary.sqlite";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
```

create table from MainActivity

```
try {             

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            myDbHelperTrivia.createDataBase();
            Log.i("CREATING", "DATABASE CREATED");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.i("CREATE", "Exception Caught! ", e);

        }                           

        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            Log.i("OPENING", "DATABASE OPENED");  
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            Log.i("OPEN", "Exception Caught! ", e);

        }
```

Comment: can you upload the code of create table ?

Comment: its edited now.. the code has been included

Comment: I do not see any create table line

Comment: please try to use this on your android phone and search for the table if it exist after getting the error https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager

Comment: @Kedarnath its included now sorry

Comment: @Mahan the database is existing

Comment: @ChristianBurgos, No, its not included, You are just calling a create table method, there should be a query like `create table.....` just like you are executing select query, `SELECT entry FROM defintionstbl where entry = '`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping guys but i just changed the getEntry method to this.. rawQuery gave alot of error but this new method is good to go..

```
public String getEntry(String l) throws SQLException {
        String[] columns = new String[] { "_id",
                "entry", "definition" };
        Cursor c = myDataBase.query("definitionstbl", columns,
                "entry" + "='" + l + "'", null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            if (c.getCount() <= 0) {
                return null;
            }
            String entry = c.getString(1);
            return entry;
        }

        return null;
    }
```